# Java: Read file: no good output

Tags: java, file

I updated the code but I get still a null value in my textfield. In the console I can see everything from the file WandelaarBestand. Maybe It has something to do with converting number to string.But when I wan't to dat that with int getal I get nothing. Without int getal I get a Null value in my textfield but I can still see everething from my file in my console.

Here you can find my updated code.

```
public class geefInfo implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    BufferedReader in;
String regel="";
int getal;
    try {
    in=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("WandelaarBestand.txt"));
            while((regel=in.readLine())!=null){             
            getal=Integer.parseInt(regel);
            System.out.println(regel);
            }
            in.close();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e6) {
            e6.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("kan file niet vinden");


        } catch (IOException e7) {
            e7.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("fout bij lezen of sluiten file");
        }

            info.setText(""+regel);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you closing the BufferedFileReader object? This is important.

Comment: You're not getting either of your error messages?

Comment: Your code reads the file and prints the lines, but does not store the data that was read anywhere.

Comment: What is naam and Wandelaar.zoekOp(naam2) in your code?

Comment: You read the file and then print out. You should see this lines in in the console if your file is not empty. You never actually use the data.

Comment: How are you setting the value into your textfield? (which i assume is the naam variable). The 'System.out.println(line);' doesn't set the textfield value!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your second try block you print out the line - so far so good.
But your line:

```
String naam2=naam.getText();
```

does not make any sense, because naam is never set and in the follwing if statement you just use naam2, which is null as well.

Also try to close your reader, it can get messy if you don't.

Hope that helps a bit

Comment: I have closed my reader, but I still get a null value in my textfield.
The 'String naam2=naam.getText();' comes from the textfield name, when I type in a name, I get all the info about this person. But my main problem is that i get my info in the console but not in my panel (in my textfield or textarea).